# Is officecdn.microsoft.com.edgesuite.net an official Microsoft server?

Tags: microsoft-office

Is the following file served from Microsoft servers?

```
http://officecdn.microsoft.com.edgesuite.net/db/492350F6-3A01-4F97-B9C0-C7C6DDF67D60/media/en-us/HomeStudent2019Retail.img
```

Just want to make sure it's safe to download.

Comment: edgesuit.net is a domain for Akamai CDN, that Microsoft uses. It's common for large files to be served over CDNs.

Comment: Thanks! Please post it as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edgesuit.net is a domain for Akamai CDN, that Microsoft uses. It's common for large files to be served over CDNs.

You can verify this by checking the WHOIS of [the domain](https://whois.domaintools.com/edgesuite.net)

```
domain: edgesuite.net
DomainName: EDGESUITE.NET
Registry Domain ID: 68698282_DOMAIN_NET-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.akamai.com
Registrar URL: http://www.akamai.com
Updated Date: 2017-04-03T20:03:50.0000Z
Creation Date: 2001-04-02T15:41:08.0000Z
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2023-04-02T15:41:08.0000Z
Sponsoring Registrar: Akamai Technologies, INC.
Sponsoring Registrar IANA ID: 2480
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: 
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.6174443076
Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited
Domain Status: serverDeleteProhibited https://icann.org/epp#serverDeleteProhibited
Domain Status: serverTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#serverTransferProhibited
Domain Status: serverUpdateProhibited https://icann.org/epp#serverUpdateProhibited
Registrant Name: Hostmaster Billing
Registrant Organization: Akamai Technologies, inc.
```

At the same time, the subdomain used by Microsoft, [officecdn.microsoft.com also points to Akamai](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/officecdn.microsoft.com) indicating that it is indeed fronted by Akamai, for Microsoft

```
dig +all officecdn.microsoft.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.13-Ubuntu <<>> +all officecdn.microsoft.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10054
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;officecdn.microsoft.com.       IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
officecdn.microsoft.com. 125    IN      CNAME   office.c2r.akadns.net.
office.c2r.akadns.net.  124     IN      CNAME   2-01-3f20-0003.cdx.cedexis.net.
2-01-3f20-0003.cdx.cedexis.net. 124 IN  CNAME   office-prod.edgekey.net.
office-prod.edgekey.net. 665    IN      CNAME   office-prod.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net.
office-prod.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net. 665 IN CNAME e1723.dscd.akamaiedge.net.
e1723.dscd.akamaiedge.net. 19   IN      A       88.221.40.105
```